# Eigen C++: How can I fixed the values after a random matrix initialization?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

It seems that in Eigen package, the coefficients keep changing after a random matrix initialization. Some illustration codes and output are listed below. We expect that X.transpose() is the transpose of the first X. But it is a transpose of another random matrix!

How can I fixed the those values after random matrix initialization?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>


using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
int main(){
  auto X = MatrixXi::Random(2,2);
  cout << X << endl;
  cout << "---------" << endl;
  cout << X.transpose() << endl;
  cout << "---------" << endl;
  cout << X << endl;
  cout << "---------" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-1073725017   548908249
 -791266575   -88798166
---------
  70367106 -603530552
-972714280  384109054
---------
 385036099 -250177384
 933495885   41696341
---------
```

Comment: MatrixXi::Random(2,2) returns an expression, and if you use auto X, X has the expression type. `cout << X << endl;` will then evaluate the expression, so you get different results. You should do `MatrixXi X = MatrixXi::Random(2,2)`.

Comment: Or you can do `auto X = MatrixXi::Random(2,2).eval();`;

Answer (score 6):

[Don't use `auto` with Eigen unless you know what you're doing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#TopicPitfalls_auto_keyword). The result of `auto X = MatrixXi::Random(2,2);` is an expression that creates a random matrix when evaluated. It's getting evaluated again and again at each call of `cout`. Instead use `MatrixXi X = MatrixXi::Random(2,2);`.